# Getting the position of an element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to get the position of an element in XSLT.

Input:

```
<parent_root>
  <root>
    <ele>
      <fig/>
    </ele>
    <got/>
    <ele>
      <fig/>
    </ele>
    <got/>
    <got/>
    <ele>
      <fig/>
    </ele>
    <got/>
  </root>
</parent_root>
```

Output should be:

```
fig_1
fig_2
fig_3
fig_4
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="fig">
  <xsl:when test="parent::ele/following-sibling::got">
    <xsl:variable name="ID2" select="parent::ele/following-sibling::got/position()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('fig_','$ID2')"/>
  </xsl:when>
</xsl:template>
```

The error I am getting:

`A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the third argument of concat() (1, 2, ...)`

How can I solve this? I am using XSLT 2.0. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position()` function is relative to the current template, so it will always return `1` in your case. But you can easily achieve a similar function by counting the preceding `<root>` ancestor elements of your current `<fig>` element:

```
<xsl:template match="fig">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('fig_',count(ancestor::root/preceding-sibling::root)+1,'&#xa;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

The last part of the `concat()` function, `'&#xa;'`, is just there to provide the well formatted output of

```
fig_1
fig_2
fig_3
```

---

**EDIT, because the question was changed:**
To get all `<got>` elements and count all of its preceding `<got>` elements, you can use the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="got">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('fig_',count(preceding::got)+1,'&#xa;')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Its output, which matches all `<got>` elements, is:

```
fig_1
fig_2
fig_3
fig_4
```

If you would match the `<fig>` elements, you would only get three nodes as output instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want the count of `got`. I edited my description. Please check it

Comment: I added a second part of my answer.

Comment: Yeah. I tried with it. But get the same error still.

Comment: Well, of course you're right in some way. But otherwise, that's impossible, because the `concat(...)` function of my answers is composed of exactly three items: `xs:string`, `xs:integer`, `xs:string`. So the error should not occur.

Comment: And in the case of your question: `<xsl:value-of select="concat('fig_','$ID2')"/>` also cannot give you that error, because it erroneously is a concatenation of two strings and **not** a concatenation of a string and a variable.

Comment: I have done a small mistake... I removed several `root` element. Please consider that.

Comment: My answer still works, but I still cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: @xsltlife If you want the count of `got` then your result should be 1, 2 and 4. Please edit your question and clarify the logic. --- Note that repeated counting of preceding siblings is expensive. Usually it's better to apply templates in such way that the `position()` function will return the expected result.